# Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground with Firebase Messaging: error 500, Internal error encountered

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, oauth2-playground

I am testing a Firebase Message to my project. I am using the OAuth 2.0 playground to send the payload to the "messages:send" rest API.
However, when sending the request it is returns with "500 internet server error".
I do the same thing on another identical project (with a different project ID naturally) and it works with no problem. Does anyone know why?
I have enabled the API service in Google cloud.
The only difference is that I am logged in to a different Firebase Google account as they are 2 different projects for 2 separate clients.

EDIT: Additional information - this is only occurring when using Tokens generated from the Microsoft Edge browser. User tokens provided through Firefox and Chrome work fine.

HTTP Method: POST

Request URI: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myprojectnamehere/messages:send

Request:

```
POST /v1/projects/myprojectnamehere/messages:send HTTP/1.1
 Host: fcm.googleapis.com
 Content-length: 867
 Content-type: application/json
 Authorization: Bearer yj29.a0AV...........(removed for example code)
 {
     "message": {
         "token": "thetokenId...(removed for example code)",
         "data": {
             "body":"Body of Your Notification in data",
             "title":"Title of Your Notification in data",
             "image":"http://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-rubber-style-red-260nw-1811246308.jpg",
             "icon":"http://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-rubber-style-red-260nw-1811246308.jpg",
         }
     }
 }
```

Response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 Content-length: 253
 X-xss-protection: 0
 X-content-type-options: nosniff
 Transfer-encoding: chunked
 Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
 Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
 -content-encoding: gzip
 Cache-control: private
 Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 14:17:43 GMT
 X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
 Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
 Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
 {
   "error": {
     "status": "INTERNAL", 
     "message": "Internal error encountered.", 
     "code": 500, 
     "details": [
       {
         "errorCode": "INTERNAL", 
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hit this exact same error message with an app in production. The device type that was intended for a notification to send to was an iOS device running 16.3. This seems to only occur on occasion, specifically with iOS devices. No clue what's going on but the 500 error along with this only being temperamental, makes me feel like this is a Firebase issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with Edge.  It is only occurring when using Tokens generated from the Microsoft Edge, but not each time. User tokens provided by Chrome work fine.